# Python log into Voobly

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I've read through dozens of pages on how to log into a web page using Python, but I can't seem to make my code work. I'm trying to log into a site called "Voobly", and I'm wondering if there might be something specific to Voobly that is making this more difficult. Here is my code:

```
import requests

loginURL = "https://www.voobly.com/login"
matchUrl = "https://www.voobly.com/profile/view/124993231/Matches"

s = requests.session()
loginInfo = {"username":"myUsername", "password":"myPassword"}

firstGetRequest = s.get(loginURL) # Get the login page using our session so we save the cookies

postRequest = s.post(loginURL,data=loginInfo) # Post data to the login page, the data being my login information

getRequest = s.get(matchUrl) # Get content from a login - restricted page

response = getRequest.content.decode() # Get the actual html text from restricted page

if "Page Access Failed" in response: # True if I'm blocked
    print("Failed")
else: # If I'm not blocked, I have the result I want
    print("Worked!") # I can't achieve this
```

Comment: The form is submitted to `/login/auth`

Comment: I've tried adding "/auth" to the loginURL and the error still persists

Comment: Then you may have to set a user-agent or referer or other headers. Sorry, i can't help more since i don't have an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623406/python-log-into-voobly/49630016#comment86253914_49623406), the login form is submitted to `/login/auth`. But, the cookie is generated from the `/login` URL.

Use the following code:

```
form = {'username': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWORD}

with requests.Session() as s:
    # Get the cookie
    s.get('https://www.voobly.com/login')
    # Post the login form data
    s.post('https://www.voobly.com/login/auth', data=form)
    # Go to home page
    r = s.get('https://www.voobly.com/welcome')
    # Check if username is in response.text
    print(USERNAME in r.text)
    # True

    r2 = s.get('https://www.voobly.com/profile/view/124993231/Matches')
    if "Page Access Failed" in r2.text:
        print("Failed")
    else:
        print("Worked!")
    # Worked!
```

**Note:** The *Go to home page* part is not at all needed for the login. It's used just to show that the login is successful.

Comment: It works, fantastic! For my future reference, how did you know to use /login for the cookies?

Comment: The main login form is available on the /login page. The /login/auth URL is only used to post the data; which is posted from the /login page. This tells that the cookie is generated on this page.